# Return employee salary greater than manger salary from a single all in one employees table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i am new to sql journey and got stuck on one query , i want to return employee having salary greater than their manager  , only one table is there,
there are employee having unique id

[click here for my sample database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMUyC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't access your image link, but here is a simple example:

```sql
SELECT emp.name 
FROM employee emp 
INNER JOIN employee mgr ON emp.managerid = mgr.id AND emp.salary > mgr.salary
```

Comment: . . The `left join` is definitely gratuitous in this case.

Comment: Why?  Can you explain?

Comment: . . Well, there's not much of a comparison to make if there is no matching manager.

Comment: In general, there is no point LEFT JOINing a table from which you select no data. The situation is confused in your case, because although you wrote 'LEFT JOIN', your query actually executes an INNER JOIN. This is because of your WHERE clause, which includes a comparison operator on the LEFT JOINed table. To prove that it executes a LEFT JOIN, you can execute EXPLAIN EXTENDED [your quey] followed by SHOW WARNINGS;

Comment: Yeah, you guys are right.  I changed it to an `INNER` join.  Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where e.salary > (select m.salary
                  from employees m
                  where m.id = e.employee_id
                 );
```

Comment: this is much simpler approach towards querying my desired data , i wanted to know if there is any advantage of using joins over this approach or vice versa?

Comment: @RaviKhatri . . . The two should be comparable from a performance perspective, so it is a matter of choice.